# Can't load matplotlib.pyplot from script

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to run the contourf example from the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.py).
When I run it from a python shell, everything works well, but when I run it as a script (python contourf_demo.py), the following error rises:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "matplotlib.py", line 3, in
>
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> File "/home/user/dir/contourf_demo.py", line 3, in
>
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> ImportError: No module named pyplot

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and the problem comes when importing:

> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I have tried using different ways to call the import (such as from matplotlib import pyplot), but it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't import a module named **XYZ** from a file called **XYZ.py**, because Python would interpret that you are trying to import the file itself.

Change your file from matplotlib.py to anything else.